# How to show a TextView Loading... at bottom of ListView

Tags: android, android-listview

I've a `ListView` that matches the whole layout (basically a `ListActivity` or `ListFragment`). I want to show a "Loading..." `TextView`at the bottom of the `ListView` when it's scrolled to the bottom.

For example, when I scroll down to end of `ListView`, it shows a `TextView` on the `ListView` and says "Loading...", and when It loads new data, the `ListView` populates and the `TextView` is gone.

Comment: Have realtive layout and put textview top

Comment: @mohsen Its call `Load More Items`. For that you have to use `PullToRefreshView` or add footer to `ListView` and apply a condition in `onScroll()` method of `ListView`..

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to display a toast when you scroll to the bottom of your listview...you can simply do it like this

```
if (yourListView.getLastVisiblePosition() == yourListView.getAdapter().getCount() -1 &&
    yourListView.getChildAt(yourListView.getChildCount() - 1).getBottom() <= yourListView.getHeight())
{
    //Make the Toast
    Toast.makeText(context, "Hey! list bottom reached", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
```

NOTE: context = yourActivityName.this

Comment: I don't think that's even remotely what he is wanting. Have you really not seen what he is asking for?